# Can I use UDAFs in window functions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a user-defined aggregate function. It concatenates all accumulated values in to a list (`ArrayType`). It's called `EdgeHistory`.

If I don't specify the window it works fine. It returns an array of all the `list`s. But with the following example it fails:

```
case class ExampleRow(n: Int, list: List[(String, String, Float, Float)])

val x = Seq(
  ExampleRow(1, List(("a", "b", 1f, 2f), ("c", "d", 2f, 3f))),
  ExampleRow(2, List(("a", "b", 2f, 4f), ("c", "d", 4f, 6f))),
  ExampleRow(3, List(("a", "b", 4f, 8f), ("c", "d", 8f, 12f)))
)

val df = sc.parallelize(x).toDF()

val edgeHistory = new EdgeHistory()

val y = df.agg(edgeHistory('list).over(Window.orderBy("n").rangeBetween(1, 0)))
```

It throws an error:

```
STDERR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: EdgeHistory('list) is not supported in a window operation.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec.withAggregate(WindowSpec.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.over(Column.scala:1052)
    at szdavid92.AnalyzeGraphStream$.main(AnalyzeGraphStream.scala:75)
```

The error message seems pretty straightforward. It seems you cannot define UDAFs in windows.
Do I understand correctly?
Why is this limitation?

**UPDATE**

I tried with SQL syntax and I get a related error

```
df.registerTempTable("data")
sqlContext.udf.register("edge_history", edgeHistory)

val y = sqlContext.sql(
  """
    |SELECT n, list, edge_history(list) OVER (ORDER BY n ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    |FROM data
  """.stripMargin)
```

that is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Couldn't find window function edge_history;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ResolveHiveWindowFunction$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$3.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ResolveHiveWindowFunction$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$3.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:288)
```

Comment: _Do I understand correctly?_  - Yes. _Why is this limitation?_ - Because Spark Window functions in < 2.0 depend on Hive to window functions. There is no native mechanism.

Comment: Is this working for >= 2.0?

Comment: As far as I remember It should work just fine.